# How can you find a value in a dictionary where the key contains a space?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, whitespace, key-value

I'm dealing with a dictionary that I cannot change - so removing the space is unfortunately not an option.

I'm trying to find out how to call a value for a key when the key has space(s).
The keys in this dictionary are all strings. Some are 'word1 word2' others are practically sentences. See the example below.

Exampledict: {'colour banana': 'yellow', 'brand of car': 'mercedes benz', 'type': 'sale}

How does one get the value of keys like that?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It seems like the obvious answer is just to access it like any other key, such as via `example_dict['brand of car']`; is there some subtlety I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for all keys in the dictionary that contain a space, you can use:

```py
example = {'colour banana': 'yellow', 'brand of car': 'mercedes benz', 'type': 'sale'}

print({k: v for k, v in example.items() if ' ' in k})
```

Which returns

```
{'colour banana': 'yellow', 'brand of car': 'mercedes benz'}
```

---

If it's just a question of finding the value, then the space doesn't matter. You can use `example['colour banana']`